# ruby performance - is &: slower than just calling method?

Tags: ruby, performance

Out of following 2 options which is faster?

```
something {|i| i.foo }
something(&:foo)
```

I read somewhere that `something(&:foo)` is transformed into `something {|i| i.send(:foo) }`. Is it true?

If that is true, the question becomes - which is faster? `i.foo` or `i.send(:foo)`?

Any any case, which one should be used for better performance?

Comment: Looks like a pointless micro-optimization to me, either way.

Comment: Have you benchmarked all three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby it is quite easy to write such a (micro) benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

VALUES = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.compare!

  x.report('symbol') do
    VALUES.each(&:odd?)
  end

  x.report('method') do
    VALUES.each do |value|
      value.odd?
    end
  end

  x.report('send') do
    VALUES.each do |value|
      value.send(:odd?)
    end
  end
end
```

(latest version is https://github.com/pascalbetz/benchmarks/blob/master/symbol_vs_proc.rb)

```
Ruby 1.9.3
symbol:  1349424.7 i/s
method:  1049894.7 i/s - 1.29x slower
send:   929240.4 i/s - 1.45x slower


Ruby 2.2.2
symbol:  1358391.5 i/s
method:  1146686.4 i/s - 1.18x slower
send:   820392.7 i/s - 1.66x slower


JRuby 9.0.5.0
symbol:  2959040.8 i/s
method:  2016911.1 i/s - 1.47x slower
send:  1305816.9 i/s - 2.27x slower
```

This is a different result as what Sawa explained in his answer.

Comment: Why not put the code here? It's not very long and that would ensure that it will live forever.

Comment: Cary, thanks for the feedback. I started to put my benchmarks into this repo for me to have them in one place. But of course it makes more sense to include it here.